# Different format of date is valid in query string on different VMs with the same regional settings

Tags: iis, date, localization

I deployed .NET application hosted on IIS on two different VMs with Windows Server 2016 on them, the code is exactly the same. However on one machine the date in query string `30/01/2018` is parsed properly on the other it caueses HTTP 500, on this machine `2018/1/30` is a parsable string.

I compared regional settings of these machines and they're exactly the same.

Where I could also look for the reason why one machine cannot parse `dd/MM/y` string?

Comment: "why one machine cannot parse dd/MM/y string" It should be the developers' responsibility to parse the string, not IIS. So involve the developers/vendor in your troubleshoot process.

Comment: Try something similar to the following example (PowerShell): `('2018/1/30','30/01/2018') | ForEach-Object{ [datetime]::Parse( $_, ([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture))}` - both are valid datetime objects. Please [edit] the question and add **1st** appropriate language tag, and **2nd** a code snippet fatisfying the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules.